# Soma em tabela grupando por mes

Tags: php

Pessoal tenho o seguinte código abaixo e gostaria que ele me retornasse a soma dos valores separados pelo o referido mês de lançamento no PHP, pois está retornando o mês atual.

Exemplo:

> ```
> DATA         VALOR 
> 21/01/2018   200.00
> 23/02/2018   200.00 
> 25/01/2018   200.00
> ```

JANEIRO: 400.00 FEVEREIRO: 200.00

E assim por diante. Alguém que possa me ajudar?

```
<?php

     $conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','root','sistema');
     $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT sum(total) FROM pedidos GROUP BY YEAR(post_at), MONTH(post_at)  ;" );
     $linhas = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);
     while($linhas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado)){    
         echo date("m ") . 'R$: ' . $linhas[ 'sum(total)'] .'<br/>';            
?>

<?php
    }
?>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você quer obter os valores agrupados por mês? No caso de 01/01 à 31/01, você quer a soma dos registros desse mês, e assim por diante?

Comment: Sim, separando-os por mês. e retornando o mês da referida soma. No caso o meu código já agrupa, mas não me retorna o mês da soma. me retorna o mês mas não o mês de lançamento e sim o mês atual. Exemplo: 06 R$: 200
06 R$: 116
06 R$: 100
06 R$: 200

Comment: A ideia seria criar uma coluna exibindo sempre a somatória total do mês?

Comment: O código me trás sim o somatório, agrupado. mas o agrupamento me retorna um mês só para todos. O mês de junho. Onde deveria retornar outros meses. EXEMPLO: Jun - R$: 200
Jun - R$: 116
Jun- R$: 100
Jun-  R$: 200

Comment: Tem como colocar o resultado de executar `SELECT sum(total) FROM pedidos GROUP BY YEAR(post_at), MONTH(post_at)` direto no phpmyadmin com um `post_at` de exemplo ?

Comment: O problema está em `date("m")`, isso sempre retornará a data atual e não a data dos registos do banco.

Comment: E como retornar a data dos registros?

Comment: Resolvido, obrigados a todos pelos comentários, resolvi com um foreach e pegando a variável com um strtotime.